# Why are the axis labels too large when using tikzDevice and lattice?

Tags: fontsize, knitr, elsarticle, tikzdevice, lattice

I'm working on a paper that is to be submitted to an Elsevier journal. The [official guidelines](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/artwork-and-media-instructions/artwork-sizing) state that:

> As a general rule, the lettering on the artwork should have a
>   finished, printed size of 7 pt for normal text and no smaller than 6
>   pt for subscript and superscript characters.

I use the knitr + lattice + tikzDevice combination. I set the following options:

```
opts_chunk$set(include=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE,
dev="tikz", dev.args=list(pointsize=10), fig.align="center")
```

And my plot is generated with `fig.width=3.5, fig.height=3.5`. I get the following result with a call to `xyplot`, without passing any `cex` option:

[image]

The axis labels are larger than the main text, whose `normalsize` is 10pt (I think---I'm using the `elsarticle` document class with the `3p` option).

When I open one of the generated `tikz` files, I found several node declarations such as this one:

```
\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.20] at (137.00, 12.04) {Day};
```

It looks like `tikzDevice` applies a scale factor of 1.2 to the axis labels; strangely, this does not seem to be the case with graphics produced with base graphics.

Any idea why this behaviour, and what I can do to bring the size of axis labels down to the desired 7pt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posed that question I've switched to ggplot, and with that package I get the size I need by changing the `base_size` parameter of the theme:

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 7))
```

I haven't checked but I suspect something similar can be done with lattice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ggplot too, but setting the base_size as [lindelof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376431/66458) proposed didn't work for me. What did the trick was explicitly setting the font size for the axis labels:

```
ggplot(...) + theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10))
```